# T-SQL Rounding, First Truncates to LENGTH + 2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In using the T-SQL `ROUND` function I noticed what seems like weird behavior. It looks like the `ROUND` function only looks at the first digit to the right of the digit to be rounded. If I round -6.146 to one decimal I get -6.1. I would have thought it would start at the right and round each digit as it works its way to the left, like this: -6.146 -> -6.15 -> -6.2

I've observed the same behavior with Excel’s round function too.

The query below illustrates what I am describing. I may simply use the nested `ROUND` functions as shown below but I'm curious if there’s a better way and which approach is considered mathematically correct.

```
DECLARE @Num AS FLOAT

SET @Num = -6.1463

SELECT @Num [OriginalVal], ROUND(@Num, 1, 0) [SingleRound]
, ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(@Num, 3, 0), 2, 0), 1, 0) [NestedRound]
```

Results

```
OriginalVal | SingleRound | NestedRound

-6.1463     | -6.1        | -6.2
```

Comment: That isn't how rounding works. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448/rules-for-rounding-positive-and-negative-numbers

Comment: go to stack overflow...learn how to round :)

Comment: What part do you think is mathematically incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

I think the basic rule of thumb is, in rounding, you look at the 1 digit immediately to the right of the place you are rounding to. You do not extend it all the way to the very end of the right of the decimal.

http://math.about.com/od/arithmetic/a/Rounding.htm